Jupyter notebook не находит kernel
Установил на Android смартфон UserLand, через него Ubuntu, далее установил Jupyter, он запускается, но постоянно не находит Kernel, чего я только не пробовал. Ошибки вроде

tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist:
3084e6c1-c107-4ebd-88a2-23dde77bfd87)

Через Termux и Ubuntu тоже самое, через просто Termux вообще не получается установить Jupyter.

Переустановил userland и остальное, поставил Anaconda, в состав которого входит Jupyter, и опять он не находит kernel

Ошибка tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: ed191c33-a917-475e-8e23-ff999fc28a52)                                    [W 2024-12-03 07:29:56.055 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/ed191c33-a917-475e-8e23-ff999fc28a52?1733210996032 (bf0d06f0236e409686c53db072a49f46@127.0.0.1) 13.98ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы установили этот UserLand?

Здравствуйте, да
